# Map editor R & leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, visualisation

That is possible on a web map designed by R & leaflet give the opportunity to the user to draw lines, polygons, choose the colors (like a map editor)? if yes what's the package that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's no package to do this, you'd have to write something in Javascript and possibly using Leaflet plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an alpha stage project called [mapedit](http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html#editing-attributes) aimed at doing the map editing what you are asking. Quoting their "Proof of concepts":

> Drawing, Editing, Deleting Features
>
> ```
> Proof of Concept 1 | Draw on Blank Map
> Proof of Concept 2 | Edit and Delete Existing Features
> ```

But as they claimed, they are currently a long way from CRAN.